# How to declare functor parameter in Qt connect?

Tags: qt

Qt can use lambda function in signal-slot connection by using functor parameter [as shown here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#connect-5). But how to declare functor parameter in Qt connect? For example,

```
QAction* CreateAction(QString text, QObject* parent, Functor functor)
{
    QAction* action = new QAction(icon, text, parent);
    QObject::connect(action, &QAction::triggered, functor);
    return action;
}
```

Question is how to include files to let the compiler know the "Functor" type.

Comment: Where is your `Functor` type declared?

Comment: Qt declared the type Functor, as its document shows. but I cannot find where it is declared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Functor` is not a real type. It's a placeholder for Qt documentation. The real type is a template type parameter. Check `QObject.h` if you are really interested. In practice, you can use [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), which is defined in `<functional>`, in its place.

For the function in the question, the simplest change is to make it a template function:

```
template<Functor>
QAction* CreateAction(QString text, QObject* parent, Functor&& functor)
{
    QAction* action = new QAction(icon, text, parent);
    QObject::connect(action, &QAction::triggered, std::forward<Functor>(functor));
    return action;
}
```

Comment: @TobySpeight it was a snippet targeting Stephens answer, thus an example with `std::function`. Either way, there's code now ;-)

Answer (score -2):

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#connect-5

A functor is just a `void *` or a void pointer.  It might need to be static.  This seems similar to a regular call back function.

Here is an example from the documentation:

```
void someFunction();
QPushButton *button = new QPushButton;
QObject::connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, someFunction);
```

Comment: It's not a void*. Read the header. http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtbase/blobs/stable/src/corelib/kernel/qobject.h#line243