# Pass QTimer::singleShot to std::async using std::bind

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, stdbind

The following code starts a non-blocking timer that will launch the function `myFunc` after one second:

MyClass.h:

```
std::future<void> timer_future_;
```

MyClass.cpp:

```
timer_future_ = std::async(

        std::launch::async,
        [this] { QTimer::singleShot(1000,
                                    [this] {this->myFunc();}
                                    );
               }
    );
```

I would like to replace the lambda functions with `std::function`s. I have successfully replaced the second lambda as follows:

```
timer_future_ = std::async(

        std::launch::async,
        [this] { QTimer::singleShot(1000, 
                                    std::bind(&MyClass::myFunc, this)
                                    );
               }
    );
```

**How can I now replace the first lambda with another `std::bind()` call?**

Note that the function `QTimer::singleShot` is from the Qt libraries; its documentation is [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#singleShot-4). Its prototype is:

```
void QTimer::singleShot(int msec, Functor functor)
```

As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15449792/how-to-declare-functor-parameter-in-qt-connect), the definition of the Functor type can be found in [`QObject.h`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtwebengine/src/3rdparty/chromium/third_party/webrtc/rtc_base/bind.h.html#_ZNK3rtc7Functor12CallFunctionENS_8sequenceIJXspT_EEEE). It says:

```
template <class FunctorT, class R, typename... Args> class Functor { /*...*/ }
```

After some research, I understand that the `std::bind()` that will replace the first lambda must take account of the following:

- `QTimer::singleShot` is an overloaded function, so [I must use a cast to disambiguate the call to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4159487/stdbind-overload-resolution)
- `QTimer::singleShot` is a static member function, so [the pointer to it must resemble a pointer to a non-member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21401552/stdbind-a-static-member-function-inside-the-class)

I have made several unsuccessful attempts, the last of which was:

```
timer_future_ = std::async(
        std::launch::async,
        std::bind( ( void(*) (int, Functor<const std::function<void(void)>,void>) )&QTimer::singleShot,
                  1000,
                  std::bind(&MyClass::myFunc, this)
                  )
);
```

For this code, the MSVC compiler returned the error message

```
error: C2059: syntax error: ')'
```

on the third line.

*Why don’t I just use the lambdas which are already working?* The answer is simply that trying to use std::bind() instead is teaching me more about the various features of the C++ language and how to use them.

---

**EDIT:** Code that implements Kuba Ober's answer:

```
QTimer::singleShot(1000, [this] {
    timer_future_ = std::async(
                std::launch::async,
                std::bind(&MyClass::myFunc, this)
                );
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The timer requires an event loop, and `std::async` will invoke it in a worker thread that doesn't have a running event loop. I question why would you ever want to do it?

If you want to run something in a worker thread after a delay, run the timer in a thread that has an event loop, and fire off the async action from that timer.

Comment: Thank you, you are right. I was trying to run a timer without blocking the event loop. I should have put the `async()` call inside the `QTimer::singleShot()` call. I've added working code that follows this approach at the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Count opening and closing brackets and add a semicolon

Comment: Sorry, a typo has left the last bracket and semicolon outside the code block which shows my attempt. I have edited it. This typo was not in the code that I tried to compile.